# How to specify hostname for the running container?

Tags: linux, lxc, docker

I'm having trouble setting the hostname on a running docker container. I'm also having trouble understanding how to specify hostname **after** the image is started.

I started a container from an image I downloaded:

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:80 -p 2222:22 oskarhane/docker-wordpress-nginx-ss
```

But I forgot to specify hostname through `-h`; how can I specify the hostname now that the container is running?

Comment: Can you just stop the container and start it again supplying a hostname?

Comment: AFAIK that only works when you `run` an image, not when you start a container.

Comment: Sometimes all you want is to see the bash command prompt with a proper name. If that is the case, you can edit the PS1 value in .bashrc. Look at https://askubuntu.com/a/549150/55365 for suggestions. In any PS1 you can add a (colored) string surrounded by * or # to set it apart, with the name of the server or service.

Comment: @dawud you can not give a new hostname when runing `docker restart`  [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/restart/)

Comment: Related: [How to handle specific hostname like -h option in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28898787/55075).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Edit `/etc/hostname` is one thing for which you need ssh access inside the container. Otherwise, you can spin up the container with `-h` option.

To set the host and domain names:

```
$ docker run -h foo.bar.baz -i -t ubuntu bash
root@foo:/# hostname
foo
root@foo:/# hostname -d
bar.baz
root@foo:/# hostname -f
foo.bar.baz
```

Comment: You can `docker exec /bin/bash` on a running container, no need to install `ssh` (which is imho a bad practice for administration purposes).

Comment: You may also want to edit /etc/hosts that it is correctly resolved into an address.

Comment: You can not change the hostname in a running container with `hostname`(missing capability). Running `docker run -h <hostname> <image> <container-name>` creates a *new* container with the given hostname.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You cannot change hostname of an existing container.

Comment: @Dojo, the answer does mention "otherwise"

Answer (score 9):

Stop container and service

```
sudo docker stop CONTAINER_NAME
sudo service docker stop
```

Edit config file (JSON) [You should make backup first]

**/var/lib/docker/containers/CONTAINER_ID/config.json**

Replace

> "Hostname":"WHATEVER"

with

> "Hostname":"NEW_HOSTNAME"

Start container and service

```
sudo service docker start
sudo docker start CONTAINER_NAME
```

(Optionally you can also attach docker)

```
sudo docker attach CONTAINER_NAME
```

---

Details about dockers (i.e. CONTAINER_NAME, CONTAINER_ID) can be obtained by running

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

Comment: doesn't work. get overwritten everytime I start the container.

Comment: that's strange. i have just reproduced these steps and it still works. docker version 1.7.1. are you sure you did close container and service before you edited the file?

Comment: Works on Docker 17.04.0-ce, when editing /etc/hostname didn't. If you haven't created the container yet, the other answer with -h is better, but in my case I had already gone to the trouble of setting up the container and didn't want to recreate it just to set the hostname.

Comment: Doesn't work `Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be`

Answer (score 7):

In case you use `--net=host` then you can't change the hostname from `-h` or from inside the docker.

See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5708

Answer (score 5):

Restarting the container would be the easiest option - but you may also edit /etc/hostname and go from there.

Comment: Editting `/etc/hostname` has no effect after restart, since it is overwritten each time with the "real" hostname, managed by docker. You can not run `hostname` on the container, since the container has no capabilities for that operation (by default, and you do not want to change that)

Comment: And editting `/etc/hostname` and not restarting the container has no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/changing-docker-hostnames-namespaces describes a way to do this. Basic idea is to use `docker inspect` to obtain the pid of the container, then enter the uts namespace of the container via `nsenter`. Running `hostname` inside that namespace will change the hostname for the docker instance that shares that namespace.

Comment: please add the solution directly here, and not an external link which may dissappear

Answer (score 0):

As a few others have pointed out, this can be changed for containers by modifying the `config.v2.json` file.

Just be sure the Docker service is stopped before the file is edited, else it will be OVERWRITTEN. The steps MUST be done in this order

- Stop the Container
- Stop the Docker service
- Modify the - `/var/lib/docker/containers/CONTAINER_ID/config.v2.json` - file
- Start up the Docker service
- Start the container

This has been confirmed working for me on Docker v17.05.0-ce, on a container using `--net=host`. Modifying the `/etc/hostname` file does not work and the file is just overwritten.

Answer (score -3):

In

```
 /var/lib/docker/containers/CONTAINER/config.json
```

find and set

```
"Config":{"Hostname":"utils","Domainname":"mysite.com", ...}
```

Comment: Doesn't work `Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be`. Config gets overwritten, who knows from where. And the hostname itself does not change after restart.